# Cannot keep dependency version in gradle.properties

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I need to keep versions of dependencies in gradle.properties.

gradle.properties:

```
springBootVersion = '2.1.9.RELEASE'
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.9.RELEASE'
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            failOnVersionConflict()
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    dependencyManagement {
        dependencies {
            dependency "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
            dependency "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}"
        }
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 11
    targetCompatibility = 11

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }
}
```

settings.gradle:

```
include 'api'
```

api/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

archivesBaseName = 'phone-gift-processing-api'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Output of `./gradlew clean build`:

```
> Task :api:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':api:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':api:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:'2.1.9.RELEASE'.
     Required by:
         project :api
```

I.e., Gradle uses `springBootVersion`, but fails to bind the dependency for some reason.

When I replace `${springBootVersion}` by `${springBootVersion}`, build is successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the format wrong in `gradle.properties`. Instead of this:

`springBootVersion = '2.1.9.RELEASE'`

Try this:

`springBootVersion=2.1.9.RELEASE`

(The spaces are optional, but the important part is that you should not have the quotation marks around the value.)

Comment: Exactly, I forgot that .properties is not a gradle file. Thanks!